# Do I use transactions to roll back an entity that was just saved in my db using EF Core?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, transactions, rollback

I need to add a db entity and then call a service [(Stripe)](https://stripe.com) to create a Connect account. If the service call to Stripe fails and I receive an exception from it, how do I roll back my db entity so that it removes it from the db? [EF Core Transactions?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)

I want to do something like this:

```
var UserStripeAccount = new UserStripeAccount {
  UserId = userFromRepo.Id,
  // other fields here
};

try {
   // call Stripe API here to create account
   var service = new AccountService();
   Stripe.Account account = await service.CreateAsync(options);       
} catch(StripeException ex) {
   // roll back entity so it's removed from db
   // return some error message to user
}
```

**Question** - When calling

> context.SaveChanges();

using transactions, does this add and save a new entity(row) in the db or is the new entity only created in the database when the

> transaction.Commit();

is called??

Comment: If you have started transaction explicitly, data will be accepted by database only after `Commit`.

Comment: Why not try to add the connect account first, the UserId can be obtained from a sequence, and if that succeeds then add to the db? I presume adding the connect account is more likely to fail than inserting into the db.

Comment: @Aardvark If I add a new Connect account first and then try to create a new entity in the db and that fails, it would be even more problematic. Then I would have a Stripe account, but no db record of it to show my user.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv can you explain what you mean by "started transaction explicitly, data will be accepted by database"?

Comment: When you start transaction by `BeginTransaction` it means explicitly. I do not understand what is not clear from documentation link that you have posted.